# How can I correct the Windows environment variable path for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Recently, I made a mistake and erased all my environment variables from Windows. I (tried) to write them one by one, but Visual Studio Code didn't work well.

Path (the one **I** set in "PATH"):

```
D:\Microsoft VS Code\
```

When I run "code" in the prompt, it does initialize Visual Studio Code, but in "debug" mode (I think; I really don't know), the prompt doesn't close and when I do, Visual Studio Code closes as well.

Is there a way to fix it? When I downloaded it, it could run in the prompt just fine.

[When running the Visual Studio Code through prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dqf1F.png)

Comment: Did you have %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin in your Path environment variable?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61819991/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of to get this correctly in the path statement is to uninstall Visual Studio Code and then install it again.

If the Visual Studio Code install adds the entry to the path, doing this will cause it to add all the appropriate path entries again.

Comment: Yeah, i thought that too, but  if it had an way, i'd love to learn... you know..

Comment: I went and looked at where my path is set to and it is pointing to: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin

Answer (score 0):

Just set the correct environment variable as following...

```
D:\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```